# composer keeps installing an old version of laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Running into an issue with composer where I am trying to run a standard install of laravel:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

but it keeps trying to install:

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.28)
```

I have tried the following:

- `composer clear-cache`
- `composer self-update`
- `rm -rf vendor` , `clear-cache` , `composer install`

nothing seems to be working... any ideas why composer is stuck in this old state?

Comment: have you trie `composer update`

Comment: What version of composer and php are you running? Laravel latest versions require php > 7.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try that...

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel=5.3.* blog
```

Then

```
composer update
```

Also Try running `composer global update` to update the Laravel installer in Composer.

If this both options also not working then check PHP Version.

You'll have to install a newer php version.

Comment: i had an old version of PHP running so composer was smarter then me! it was installing the correct version for the php -v I had installed. Updated my local php version to 7.2 and now laravel 5.7 is installing correctly! Thanks all!

Answer (score 11):

Check your PHP version. I suspect you are running PHP7.0, but Laravel 5.6 and above requires PHP7.1. In which case composer will only install the latest version available for your PHP version.

If you want to install a newer version of Laravel, consider updating your PHP version to 7.1.3 or greater.

Answer (score 1):

try to update PHP and composer to latest version of them,
for PHP install latest XAMPP local server it will automatically installs latest PHP version in your system after updating PHP create an path variable in your system and after that install composer latest version with the help of composer installer and select that path variable while installation of composer and it will capture the latest PHP version from your XAMPP PHP file, now everything will be fine let's try again to require laravel/installer command it will install latest laravel version automatically hope this information will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

The stable version is always given to the developer so laravel gives that only,
if you want to get the latest one then you need to specify the version while installing. like

`composer create-project laravel/laravel projectName 5.6.*`

the version of the PHP is also matters.